# Constructores anidados

Tags: javascript, poo, objeto, javascript-objeto, constructor

Estaba haciendo un ejercicio de constructor y prototype, lo que estoy haciendo es:

```
function alAzar (){
   
    alAzar.prototype.nombre= "Mi nombre"
  
    alAzar.prototype.saludar= function(){
        return "Hola, mi nombre es "+this.nombre
    }
    alAzar.prototype.nuevoAuto= function (){
           alAzar.nuevoAuto.nombre= "Fiat 1" //(ESTO ESTA MAL)
    }
}
```

---

EL PROBLEMA:
Alguien me puede explicar como puedo acceder a la función `nuevoAuto` ya que lo que tendría que hacer es de esta manera:

```
let auto = new alAzar.nuevoAuto();
console.log(auto.nombre); //========== > Fiat 1 (EJEMPLO)
```

Answer (score 0):

Realmente no tienes constructores anidados, lo que haces al definir funciones con [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) es extender la funcionalidad de `alAzar()` y siempre debes ejecutar el constructor antes de poder acceder a sus métodos.

Pero hay algunas cosas a tener en cuenta:

- Todas las propiedades y métodos definidos como parte del prototipo, serán compartidos por todas las instancias de la clase, es decir, modificas para una y se actualiza en las demás
- Dentro de los métodos debes usar la palabra reservada `this` para hacer referencia a la instancia y modificar las propiedades en lugar de `alAzar.prototype.nombreDePropiedad`
- Como comenté al inicio de la respuesta, no puedes acceder a un método sin haber instanciado primero la clase: `new alAzar().nuevoAuto()`; al final del código se incluye un par de ejemplos sobre esto y es lo que resuelve tu duda

```js
function alAzar () {
    // Por lo general, las propiedades se definen en el constructor
    this.nombre = "Mi nombre";
}

// La modificación del prototipo se hace fuera de la función (o clase)
// Puedes definir propiedades como parte del prototipo,
alAzar.prototype.propiedad = 'Algo';

alAzar.prototype.saludar = function() {
    return "Hola, mi nombre es " + this.nombre;
}

// No debe ser un constructor, sino un método
alAzar.prototype.nuevoAuto = function () {
    // Las propiedades se modifican por instancia (this)
    // No por nombre de función (o clase)
    this.nombre= "Fiat 1";
}

alAzar.prototype.cambiaTodos = function() {
    // Si quieres modificar una propiedad por prototipo
    // se modifica también para otras instancias
    alAzar.prototype.propiedad = 'Cambió para todos';
    // No pasa si lo haces con this.propiedad = 'Nuevo valor';
}

// Primero debes crear la instancia (creamos dos para ver qué pasa)
let auto = new alAzar();
let auto2 = new alAzar();

// Ya puedes acceder a las propiedades y métodos
console.log(auto.nombre);
// Cambiar el nombre
auto.nuevoAuto();
console.log(auto.nombre);

// Eejcutar método que cambia propiedad en el prototipo
auto.cambiaTodos();
// Actualiza la propiedad para todas las instancias
console.log(auto.propiedad, auto2.propiedad);

// Creando instancia y ejecutando método en la misma línea
// Falla porque no devuelve la instancia de la clase
let auto3 = new alAzar().nuevoAuto();
console.log(auto3);

// Se puede reescribir el método
alAzar.prototype.nuevoAuto = function () {
    this.nombre= "Fiat 1";
    // Devolver instancia de la clase
    return this;
}

// Ahora ya no falla
let auto4 = new alAzar().nuevoAuto();
console.log(auto4);
```

En este ejemplo sobrescribí el método `nuevoAuto()` solo para demostrar cómo debe hacerse, pero lo ideal es que lo definas correctamente desde el inicio.